# ASP.NET MVC - class can no longer find his own namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 solution made of several projects:

- project.Model
- project.DAL
- **project.Web**
- etc.

**project.Web** has suddenly problems to find something inside namespace project.Web namespace (or inside child namespaces).
If I manually type "Using project...", I am only offered for others project/namespaces. As a result, compilation failed with class that cannot be found when inside this namespace hierarchy.

I assumed it is a side effect of something I made wrong but I cannot guess what.

Thanks.

Comment: are you doing pre-compile and the @using is inside razor?

Comment: I am not familiar with "pre-compile" so I assume I do use default here. For "Using...", I was referring to usage inside my HomeController.cs file

Comment: you can't use "using self" if the namespace you are trying to reference is your current namespace, can you show us some code?